# Warning editing rc.local (/etc/rc.local)

Tags: gedit

I want to edit `/etc/rc.local` to boot a driver when starting up.

But when I edit `rc.local`, terminal says:

```
(gedit:2844) gtk warning calling inhibit failed gdbus.error.:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.name.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files.
```

I am in "`sudo`" mode. I also tried `gksudo`.

Comment: Dont worry, whenever you run graphical application from terminal, these messages appear. Ignore them.

Answer (score 3):

Many applications show these messages to standard out/standard error in spite of there being no actual problem.

Note that they are warnings, and the application is likely probing for optional functionality that does not exist on your system. If you managed to write the changes you wanted to `/etc/rc.local` you should have no problem.

*However*, `sudo` is not recommended for graphical programs. `gksudo` will be able to properly manage permissions on graphical control and authority files, meaning that there is less risk of further warnings or possibly errors.